# Events fire but nothing happens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm following this course on pluralsight about making web apps using .NET Core. The author uses jQuery 2.4.3 I think and I just picked the newest jQuery myself which 3.x.

So I write the code exactly like he does:

```
(function () {
    var ele = $("#userName");
    ele.text("Some Dude");

    var main = $("#main");
    main.on("mouseenter", function () {
        main.css("background-color", "#888;");
    });
    main.on("mouseleave", function () {
        main.css("background-color", "");
    });
})();
```

And at first nothing happened when I moused over my div. It doesn't change color. Nothing much seems to register at all. So I went hunting an I found that this is how I should probably do it instead:

```
(function () {
    var ele = $("#userName");
    ele.text("Some Dude");

    var main = $("#main");
    main.on("mouseover", function () {
        console.log("enter");
        main.css("background-color", "#888;");
    })
    .on("mouseout", function () {
        console.log("out");
        main.css("background-color", "");
    });
})();
```

And while the console prints out "enter" and "out", the background color of my div still doesn't change.

What did I miss about this?

Comment: Maybe remove ";" in `main.css("background-color", "#888;")`

Comment: @schaffioverflow Yeah that was it...god damn it <.< . Make it an answer if you want and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe remove ";" in `main.css("background-color", "#888;")`